# Javascript yield inside object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-saga

So I am using [redux-saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga) and I have this **generator** function:

```
export function * getData(api, action) {
    const response = yield call(api.getData)
    if (response.ok) {
        let { data } = response;
        yield put(MyActions.responseSuccess(data))
    }
}
```

Everything works as expected, there is a request and if the response is ok I get change of state in my component.

Now I wanted to have a **websocket connection**, WAMP to be precise. I wrote the wamp function that looks like this:

```
const default_callbacks = {
    onopen: () => console.log('Default callback - onopen.')
}

const openConnection = (data, callbacks = default_callbacks) => {
    const wsuri = "wss://wssuri";
    let connection = new wamp.Connection({
      url: wsuri,
      realm: "realm1"
    });
    connection.onopen = () => {
        console.log('Connection opened')
        callbacks.onopen();
    }
    // Some code managing the data
    connection.open()
}
export default { openConnection }
```

Now what I wanted to do is to use this `openConnection` function inside my generator function, and provide callbacks that will change the state of my application (as there will be a subscription to a channel inside this `connection`). So I modified my generator functions to look like this:

```
export function * getData(api, action) {
    const response = yield call(api.getData)
    if (response.ok) {
        let { data } = response;
        yield put(MyActions.responseSuccess(data))
        const callbacks = {
            onopen: yield put(MyActions.wampConnectionOpened())
        }
        WAMP.openConnection(data, callbacks);
    } 
}
```

Now in my console I see the log saying that connection was opened, but there is no change in the state.

What am I doing wrong? Maybe my whole approach to this **problem is wrong**?

Comment: What is expected result of `const callbacks = {
            onopen: yield put(MyActions.wampConnectionOpened())
        }`?

Comment: Change of the `state` from `{ connectionOpened: false }` to `{ connectionOpened: true }`

Comment: Where is `{connecttionOpened: false}` defined? `yield` should set `value` of generator `.next()` to `put(MyActions.wampConnectionOpened())` from `getData()` call. Why is a generator function necessary?

Comment: this `getData` generator function is then imported to the `root` generator function which is used in `configureStore` function. I am a newbie in this topic, as you can see. How then should I update my state?

Comment: Not experienced with `reactjs`. Though `yield` within generator function yields the adjacent value. Not sure what the purpose of placing `yield` as the property of an object is?

Comment: The main purpose of the callbacks is to update the state. Seems like I have to jump back to reading and understanding the generator functions once again.

Comment: You mentioned here an object member that's called 'connectionOpened', but I don't see anything like that in your code in your question. Are you sure that you've added all the relevant code?

Comment: @Alon You mean `wampConnectionOpened`? It's called on `MyActions` object, which is imported into the file, and I did not think it was important to put it here.

Comment: @Ancinek you mentioned { connectionOpened: false }. Where is it declared?

Comment: @Alon it is a part my application's state. What I want is to be able to change the state from inside the `WAMP.openConnection` by passing functions (that change this state) as a `callback` object

Comment: @Ancinek then please add all the relevant code, and it will be great if you can also create a plunker

Comment: @Ancinek it looks like you understand Redux Saga. It must be a little thing that you're missing. Is MyActions.responseSuccess getting reached? Please attach it, and the place where you update your state explicitly and any other relevant code, and as I said a plunker would be great.